# Change radio button text color in Qt

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, qtgui

I have tried stylesheet, html format and palette to change the color of radio button to white but they did not work.

is there a way to change it ? in the documantation of QRadioButton there is no function for text color.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the foreground color only of Radio button you may need to provide alpha background color for that button. for example:

```
QRadioButton{ color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);}
```

This will give you white color with transparent background.

Answer (score 1):

That sound strange. Both with QtCreator and QtDesigner setting the `stylesheet` property of the QRadioButton to

```
color: white; background-color: red;
```

give you a QRadioButton with a white text on a red background
(if I understand the question)

Comment: I have tried so many times and the color of the text didn't change.

Comment: Can you post a code example (if you are trying to do this with code) of what are you trying ?

Comment: I have reinstalled the qt compiler and the problem solved :/ it was too silly and I don't know why that happened :(

Answer (score 1):

You will need to subclass `QProxyStyle` and reimplement the `drawControl()` method to catch calls with `QStyle::CE_RadioButton`.

If you look at the source for `QRadioButton::paintEvent()`:

```
QStylePainter p(this);
QStyleOptionButton opt;
initStyleOption(&opt);
p.drawControl(QStyle::CE_RadioButton, opt);
```

`initStyleOption()` does not do anything but set state data; everything is handled by the painter. Here's `QStylePainter::drawControl()`, which simply calls the current QStyle to do the job:

```
void QStylePainter::drawControl(QStyle::ControlElement ce, const QStyleOption &opt)
{
    wstyle->drawControl(ce, &opt, this, widget);
}
```

The Qt docs include information on how to subclass and load a proxy style: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html. Peek into the `QCommonStyle::drawControl()` implementation to see how Qt goes about painting the control.